# I got DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400] when send form data using dio and post method to request

Tags: flutter, http, visual-studio-code, httpclient, dio

I got when I request this data, I'm using Dio package to send request, I tried to replace the content type with application/json and I checked my header and my authorization, and also I got the same error.

and this is my request code:

```
class AddQuestion {
      addApiQuestion(
        formData,
        quizId,
      ) async {
        final String url = apiServer + 'quizzes/exam/$quizId/questions/add/';
        try {
          var response = await Dio().post(
            url,
            data: { 'data'
    "text": "Compare between Bubble sort and merge sort",
    "helping_text": "Explain",
    "score": 10,
    "status":1,
    "question_type": 1,
    "options": [
        {
            "text": "Q_4 answer_1 exam_7",
            "is_correct": false,
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "Q_4 answer_2 exam_7",
            "is_correct": false,
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "Q_4 answer_3 exam_7",
            "is_correct": true,
            "status":1
        }
    ]}
},
            options: Options(
              headers: {
                'accept': '*/*',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ${AppHelper().getToken().access}',
                'contentType': 'multipart/form-data',
              },
            ),
          );
          if (response.statusCode == 200 ||
              response.statusCode == 201 ||
              response.statusCode == 302) {
            var message = json.decode(response.statusMessage);
 
    
            return message;
          } else {

            return null;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('erro $e');
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Without specifications of your api it is hard to help you... is there a message to the error that could help narrow it down?

Comment: Does your api use multipart? Because if it does then your data should look different b/c your data is application/json.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I specified the type of content to be multipart/form in my code.

Comment: this is my data looks like in postman I'm sorry, I'm not able yet to upload image so I used a website to host the image
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2021-03-21-001641.png
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2021-03-21-001736.png

Answer (score 0):

In your data field you need to wrap it with `FormData.from`. For example look at this code from the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata) page:

```
FormData formData = FormData.from({
    "name": "wendux",
    "age": 25,
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text.txt",filename: "upload.txt")
});
response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
```

So for example your code should look like:

```
var response = await Dio().post(
            url,
            data: FormData.from({ 'data'  // note: wrapped data in FormData.from()
    "text": "Compare between Bubble sort and merge sort",
    "helping_text": "Explain",
    // ... The rest of your request.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and this is the solution:

```
class AddQuestion {
  addApiQuestion(
    formData,
    imagePath,
    quizId,
  ) async {
    printClassNameWithNumber(runtimeType, lineNumber, '$formData');
    final String url = apiServer + 'quizzes/exam/$quizId/questions/add/';
    try {
      var headers = {
        'Authorization': ' Bearer ${AppHelper().getToken().access}',
        'Cookie':
            'csrftoken=egq5rMCeyUIOTxsCsbGMJbHWnmSqAIRumXBNX2WMmp9eOXaInSDC1RoMRNvY9qz9'
      };
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
      request.fields.addAll({'data': formData});
      request.files
          .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('question_image', imagePath));
      request.headers.addAll(headers);

      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      } else {
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('nasser $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```